# Where can I find spatial data on polar fish populations?

Tags: data, spatial-database, data-collection

Where can I find spatial data on polar fish populations? I am looking specifically for polar cod, but any fish will do at this point in my project. I also need arctic ocean salinity, temperature, and sea ice coverage

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it fits within the scope of your project but good fish data at the worldbank:

http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/EN.FSH.THRD.NO

You might also want to check the Fish and Wildlife Department for whatever state/area you are in.

**ADDED**

The Alaska Fisheries Science Center looks to have good data:

http://www.afsc.noaa.gov/#

I've found that even if you can't find what you are looking for on the websites, calling these governmental organizations can be very helpful. Most all of the information they would have is public record, and most of the time, they are happy to help. Especially when it comes to science stuff and environmental projects.

Comment: Hi Craig thank you for responding to my question! I am having troubles on how to use the world back page. I am looking for Beaufort Sea so either Aalaska or Canada may work

Comment: Please see my addition to my answer above

Answer (score 1):

my fav data vendor, NASA seems to have relevant datas:

for salinity check http://aquarius.nasa.gov/, [data bank](http://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/l3?prd=SCI_V1.3_SSS&sen=Q&ctg=Evaluation)

for temperature, and sea ice coverage check [reverb's](http://reverb.echo.nasa.gov/)  product AMSR

hope it helps